# Remainder when $5^{5555}$ is divided by $10000$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

Find the remainder when $5^{5555}$ is divided by $10000$.

A step by step guide with explanation for a beginner student in modular arithmetic is needed.

Comment: Can you find $5^{5555}$ mod $625$ and $5^{5555}$ mod $16$?

Comment: See : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844558/how-to-find-last-two-digits-of-22016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $10000=2^4\times5^4$, we can use the Chinese Remainder Theorem after evaluating $5^{5555}$ modulo $2^4$ and modulo $5^4$.  The latter is easy:
$$5^{5555}\bmod 5^4=0\ .$$
For the former, start evaluating powers of $5$ modulo $2^4=16$: we have
$$5^1\equiv5\ ,\quad 5^2\equiv9\ ,\quad 5^3\equiv13\ ,\quad5^4\equiv 1\ .$$
It's not hard to see that $4$ is a factor of $5556$.  Hence
$$5^{5555}\equiv5^{4q+3}\equiv 1^q\times5^3\equiv13\ .$$
So if $x=5^{5555}$ we have
$$x\equiv13\pmod{2^4}\ ,\quad x\equiv0\pmod{5^4}$$
and the Chinese Remainder Theorem gives
$$x\equiv8125\pmod{10000}\ .$$

Comment: See also : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html

Answer (score 2):

We can use [Exponentiation by Squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring):
$$
\begin{align}
&&&\text{operation}&&\text{exponent of $5$ in base two}\\
5^1&\equiv5\pmod{10000}&&&&1_\text{two}\\
5^2&\equiv25\pmod{10000}&&\text{square}&&10_\text{two}\\
5^4&\equiv625\pmod{10000}&&\text{square}&&100_\text{two}\\
5^5&\equiv3125\pmod{10000}&&\text{multiply by }5&&101_\text{two}\\
5^{10}&\equiv5625\pmod{10000}&&\text{square}&&1010_\text{two}\\
5^{20}&\equiv625\pmod{10000}&&\text{square}&&10100_\text{two}\\
5^{21}&\equiv3125\pmod{10000}&&\text{multiply by }5&&10101_\text{two}\\
5^{42}&\equiv5625\pmod{10000}&&\text{square}&&101010_\text{two}\\
5^{43}&\equiv8125\pmod{10000}&&\text{multiply by }5&&101011_\text{two}\\
5^{86}&\equiv5625\pmod{10000}&&\text{square}&&1010110_\text{two}\\
5^{172}&\equiv625\pmod{10000}&&\text{square}&&10101100_\text{two}\\
5^{173}&\equiv3125\pmod{10000}&&\text{multiply by }5&&10101101_\text{two}\\
5^{346}&\equiv5625\pmod{10000}&&\text{square}&&101011010_\text{two}\\
5^{347}&\equiv8125\pmod{10000}&&\text{multiply by }5&&101011011_\text{two}\\
5^{694}&\equiv5625\pmod{10000}&&\text{square}&&1010110110_\text{two}\\
5^{1388}&\equiv625\pmod{10000}&&\text{square}&&10101101100_\text{two}\\
5^{2776}&\equiv625\pmod{10000}&&\text{square}&&101011011000_\text{two}\\
5^{2777}&\equiv3125\pmod{10000}&&\text{multiply by }5&&101011011001_\text{two}\\
5^{5554}&\equiv5625\pmod{10000}&&\text{square}&&1010110110010_\text{two}\\
5^{5555}&\equiv8125\pmod{10000}&&\text{multiply by }5&&1010110110011_\text{two}\\
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

> Find the remainder when $5^{5555}$ is divided by $10000$.

Also known as "find the last 4 digits of $5^{5555}$". Essentially this depends on the cycle length of 5 in $2^4$, which is $4$. So we're only interested in what $5555 \pmod 4$ is: $3$. In order to saturate the $4$-fold multiplicity of $5$ in $10000$, we'll look at $5^7 \pmod {10000}$ instead, which is our answer: $8125$

Answer (score 0):

Start by factoring $10000 = 10^4 = 2^4 \times 5^4$.

So we want to know the results mod $2^4$ and mod $5^4$.

The second is easiest: $5555 > 4$ so $5^{5555} \equiv 0 \mod 5^4$.

Now mod $2^4 = 16$: $\gcd(2^4, 5) = 1$ and $\phi(16) = 8$, so $5^8 \equiv 1 \mod 2^4$.  $5555 \equiv 3 \mod 8$, so $5^{5555} \equiv 5^3 \equiv 13 \mod 2^4$.

You want a number $x \in [0,1,\ldots, 9999]$ with $x \equiv 0 \mod 5^4$ and $x \equiv 13 \mod 2^4$.  The $0$ makes it especially easy.  You'll have
$x = 5^4 y$, and $5^4 \equiv 1 \mod 2^4$, so $y \equiv x \equiv 13 
\mod 2^4$.  You can take $y = 13$ and thus $x = 8125$.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show you an interesting pattern-

Powers of five                             Value

$5^2 =                                          25$

$5^3  =                                        125$

$5^4  =                                        625$

$5^5   =                                      3125$

$5^6  =                                      15625$

$5^7    =                                    78125$

$5^8    =                                   390625$

$5^9     =                                 1953125$

$5^{10}      =                                9765625$

$5^{11}       =                              48828125$

$5^{12}        =                            244140625$

$5^{13}         =                          1220703125$

$5^{14}          =                         6103515625$

$5^{15}           =                      3 0517578125$

$5^{16}            =                    15 2587890625$

$5^{17}             =                   76 2939453125$

$5^{18}              =                 381 4697265625$

$5^{19}               =               1907 3486328125$

$5^{20}                =              9536 7431640625$

Note that your question can be written as -"Write the last four digits of $5^{5555}$".

Now,note same interesting features of the series of power of $5$.

1. The last two digits are always $25$
2. The third digit from right is either $1$(for odd power) or $6$ (for even power).
3. Note the fourth digit from left.It cycles in the form -$3,5,8,0$.Now this is in Arithmetic Progression.You can simply use AP formula for $n-th$ term of series to find the fourth digit. [If you have problem in understanding how to use the third point of AP see this answer for help-[Solve for $b$ in $2^b\bmod11=7$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775788/solve-for-b-in-2b-bmod11-7/1776801#1776801])

Calculating we find the last four digits are-$8125$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\,\ 2^{\large 4}\mid 5^{\large 4}\!-1 = 25^{\large 2}\!-1 = 24\cdot 26,\,$ so $\ 10^{\large 4}\mid 5^{\large 4}(5^{\large 4}\!-1) = 5^{\large 8}-5^{\large 4}\ $ so

${\rm mod}\ 10^{\large 4}\!:\,\ 5^{\large 8} \equiv  5^{\large 4}\,\overset{\large \times 5^4}\Rightarrow\, 5^{12} \equiv 5^{\large 4}\overset{\large \times 5^4}\Rightarrow\, 5^{\large 16} \equiv 5^{\large 4}\,\ldots \Rightarrow\, 5^{\large 4N} \equiv 5^{\large 4} $